# I want to create a custom controller that extends Cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

I'd like to create a custom controller for a Cronjob that doesn't generate jobs in certain situations.

Is there any way to easily create a custom controller that works almost exactly like a Cronjob?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can find easy way ... but start with [How to write Kubernetes custom controllers in Go](https://medium.com/speechmatics/how-to-write-kubernetes-custom-controllers-in-go-8014c4a04235)

In the official Kubernetes GitHub repository, you can find a **controller example**, [sample-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller).

**Controller structure diagram:**

[image]